# Connect Error to IMAP using JavaMail

Tags: oauth-2.0, jakarta-mail, google-oauth

I use function "connectToImap" to get the Store object.

```
store = OAuth2Authenticator.connectToImap("imap.gmail.com", 993, email, oauth, false);
```

This is working with some users who use service account. However, users who use a normal identification, it is not working (we use the same function, always the same code).

So I don't know where is my problem. I think it is coming because of oauth but I'm not sure.

I will attach my debug where you can see the message:

```
DEBUG IMAPS: SASL no response
```

As you see in the last lines, I am sending as oauth parameter the **Access Token what I get when I rebuild my GoogleCredential object before this function**. Is it right?

[image: Debug]

Thank you,
Diego

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the [built-in OAuth2 support](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2) in [JavaMail 1.5.2](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).  I don't know why your current program isn't working but there may be some fixes in the newer version that will help.

Comment: Hello, I have set JavaMail 1.5.2 in my project and the same problem is coming. This is new log: http://oi61.tinypic.com/nmxmrs.jpg

Comment: Is it possible that there's an anti-virus or firewall between you and the server that's intercepting your communication and causing the problem?  Can you authenticate to GMail without using OAuth2?

Comment: There is no problem with firewall or similar. I can without OAuth2.